# Calculate percentage between two values and submit results in to new table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

How you would go about writing a script that calculates the percent change between two values and then submit the results in to a new MYSQL table?

Comment: Can you give some code so that we have better idea what are you doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a simple SQL query without needing to do anything in PHP at all:

Assumes table to be inserted into is called `newTable` and has two columns (`ID` which is auto_increment and `percy` which is the percentage value of `col1/col2` from table2):

```
insert into newTable 
(ID, percy) 
select 
    null, 
    col1/col2 
from 
    table2 
where 
    somecondition=someOtherCondition
```

Or if you want to get the ID (called myID) of the original row and insert the calculated percentage into the new table:

```
insert into newTable 
    (ID, percy) 
    select 
        myID, 
        col1/col2 
    from 
        table2 
    where 
        somecondition=someOtherCondition
```

Comment: ROUND((col1/col2)*100,2)

Comment: @Gustonez I don't disagree with your comment, but generally feel that keeping percentages in a `0.xx` value is better - and I certainly wouldn't round them until I was using the values - it is too easy to lose data in rounding. Better not to round until you *have* to which is normally right at the final moment when you get your answer.

Comment: yes you are right, but i suggest giving him more options. also I wanted to let you multiply the number by 100.

Comment: @Gustonez Like I said, I don't disagree mate, at that point it is personal preference. Either way might work better for user1614273 :)